# phone regex does not completely working

Tags: ruby, regex

In my country the phone numbers follow a format like this `(XX)XXXX-XXXX`. But enter phone numbers according to the pattern in input texts it's too mainstream. Some people follow, but some people don't. I'd like to make a regex to catch all possible cases. By now it look like this:

```
/^[\(]?\d{2}?[\)]?\d{4}[. -]?\d{4}$/
```

And I prepared some test cases to prove the regex's functionality

```
# GOOD PHONES #
8432115262
843211 5262
843211.5262
843211-5262
32115262
3211.5262
3211 5262
3211-5262
(84)32115262
(84)3211.5262
(84)3211 5262
(84)3211-5262

# BAD PHONES #
!@#$%*()
()32115262
()1231 3213
()1231.3213
()1231-3213
().3213
()-3213
()3213.
()3213-
3211-5a62
sakdiihbnmwlzi
```

Unfortunately, the wrong case `()32115262` is bypassing the regex. Altought it is clear why. this part `[\(]?\d{2}?[\)]?` is responsable for the mistake. From left to right, you can enter zero or one of `(`; You can enter zero or two digits; You can enter zero or one of `)`.

I'd like that part should be like this: If you put `(`, you will have to enter two digits and `)`, else you can enter zero or two digits. Something like this or with simmilar semantics is possible in regex world?

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
/^(?:\(\d{2}\)|\d{2}?)\d{4}[. -]?\d{4}$/
```

I used a non-matching group `(?: ... )` and alternation to provide two possible options for the first part of the phone number.

Either it is `\(\d{2}\)` which means brackets with exactly two digits, or it is `\d{2}?` which means two digits or empty string.

Combine these two options together with `|` (which means OR) and you get the first part of the regex above: `(?:\(\d{2}\)|\d{2}?)`

It seemed to work for all your test cases!

Answer (score 1):

try with this: `^(?:\(\d\d\)|\d\d)?\d{4}[. -]?\d{4}$`

If pattern matches `(..)` then have to match 2 digits inside.

Comment: Can you, please, explain the solution?